# How to make a search box functionality in React without using any 3rd party library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've to create a very basic search functionality in React using the plain old `input`. Search by name, username, team or id.

**Hello.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
...

class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
    };
  }

  filteredUsers = {
  [
    {
      "name": "Captain Americax",
      "username": "captain",
      "password": "User2Password",
      "team": "Alpha",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "tanzeel",
      "username": "mirza",
      "password": "qaw23",
      "team": "Beta",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Pokemon",
      "username": "captain",
      "password": "yuio",
      "team": "Alpha",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
;

  search = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.filteredUsers.forEach((user) => {
      if (user.password == 'yuio') {
        this.filteredUsers.push(user);
        console.log(this.filteredUsers);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
   return (
      <div className="container">
        <form
          onSubmit={(e) => {
            this.search(e);
          }}
        >
          <input className="search-box" placeholder="search..." type="text" />
        </form>
        <table className="table table-border table-bordered text-center table-stripped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>User id</th>
              <th>User name</th>
              <th>User password</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.filteredUsers.map((user, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{user.id}</td>
                <td>{user.name}</td>
                <td>{user.password}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

There is no error. My logic is incorrect. Here is one [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xqnp8f?file=src%2Findex.js) (a lot of other code is also there).

Comment: Use state and [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is that you need to store the value from the search input in state whenever it's updated. That way you can use that value as a criteria when you come to filter your data.

In this updated example:

1. I've moved `filteredData` outside of the component, introduced it as a prop, and initialised the state with it.
2. I've added `search` and `filtered` as new states to capture the search value, and the filtered data. It's the `filtered` state that you'll be mapping over in the render.
3. Added a new method called `updateSearch` which takes the value from the input when the `onChange` listener is triggered.
4. Updated `search` so that it looks at both the `name` and `password` property. Searching for `Pokemon` will return a result - nothing else will.
5. Updated the JSX slightly so that if `this.state.filtered` is empty there will be a message to say "No matches".

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Hello extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // New state properties
    this.state = {
      users: this.props.users,
      filtered: [],
      search: ''
    };
  }

  // Whenever the input's onChange listener is
  // triggered update the state with its value
  updateSearch = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ search: value });
  }

  // `search` now checks the value stored in the
  // search state, as well as the password
  search = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { search } = this.state;
    const filtered = users.filter(user => {
      return user.name === search && user.password === 'yuio';
    });
    this.setState({ filtered });
  };

  render() {

    const { filtered } = this.state;
        
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={this.search}>
          <input
            className="search-box" placeholder="search..."
            type="text"
            onChange={this.updateSearch}
          />
        </form>
        <table className="table table-border table-bordered text-center table-stripped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>User id</th>
              <th>User name</th>
              <th>User password</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {filtered.length ? filtered.map((user, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{user.id}</td>
                <td>{user.name}</td>
                <td>{user.password}</td>
              </tr>
            )) : <div>No matches</div>}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  
  }

}

const users = [
  {
    "name": "Captain Americax",
    "username": "captain",
    "password": "User2Password",
    "team": "Alpha",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "tanzeel",
    "username": "mirza",
    "password": "qaw23",
    "team": "Beta",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Pokemon",
    "username": "captain",
    "password": "yuio",
    "team": "Alpha",
    "id": 3
  }
];


ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello users="users" />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```